# How to get data from window.fetch() response?

Tags: javascript, json, response, fetch

I'm trying to use window.fetch() to get json from the server, but can't get the data from the response.
I have this code:

```
let url =
'https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/json/from/SYD/to/MEL/departing/2016/3/28?appId=f4b1b6c9&appKey=59bd8f0274f2ae88aebd2c1db7794f7f';
let request = new Request (url, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'no-cors'
    });

 fetch(request)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response)
        });
```

It seems that this request is successfull, I see status 200
and response body with json in network tab - [status and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CwUj.png). But in `console.log` I dont see json object - [console log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwgCA.png)

I cant understand why I dont see json in console.log

Comment: It looks to me like that site does not support CORS and you need CORS in order to get data from a cross origin with an ajax call.  That site does support JSONP so you could use that mechanism.  When you specific no-cors on a cross origin site, you are getting an opaque response back which means you aren't allowed to see that actual data returned.  You will have to fix your access rights.  If you set this request to `cors`, then it will tell you that cors headers are not present here.  It looks to me like you have to use JSONP from the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The host site you are requesting from does not appear to support CORS.  As such, you can't use `fetch()` to make a cross origin request and get the data back.  If, you change your `fetch()` request to `mode: 'cors'`, the debug console will show that the host site does not offer CORS headers to allow the browser to show you the result of the request.

When you are using `mode: 'no-cors'`, the browser is hiding the result from you (because you don't have permission to see it) and you can see the response is tagged as `opaque`.

In a little poking around on the `api.flightstats.com` site, I did see that it supports JSONP which will allow you to work around the lack of CORS support issue and successfully complete a cross origin request.

For simplicity of showing that it can work, I used jQuery to just prove that a JSONP request can be made.  Here's that code in a working snippet.  Note I changed the URL from `/json/` to `/jsonp/` and specific `dataType: "jsonp"` in the jQuery request.  This causes jQuery to add the `callback=xxxxx` query parameter and to fetch the response via that corresponding script (the JSONP method).

```js
var url =
'https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/jsonp/from/SYD/to/MEL/departing/2016/3/28?appId=f4b1b6c9&appKey=59bd8f0274f2ae88aebd2c1db7794f7f';

$.ajax(url, {dataType: "jsonp"}).then(function(response) {
 log(response);
}, function(err) {
    log("$.ajax() error:")
 log(err);
})
```

```html
<script src="http://files.the-friend-family.com/log.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yep, jsonp is worked in this case. Thanks a lot for help

Comment: @Rielon, in case you want use pure JavaScript (no jQuery), you can use https://github.com/robertodecurnex/J50Npi `J50Npi.getJSON(url, data, callback)`

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) of the `Fetch API`; you'll notice that the API offers various methods to extract the data:

- arrayBuffer()
- blob()
- json()
- text()
- formData()

Assuming the response is valid JSON (which I've noticed it doesn't seem to appear), you can use the `response.json()` function to retrieve the response data. This also uses a Promise mechanism, as for everything with the `Fetch API`.

```
response.json().then(function(data) {  
    console.log(data);  
});
```

Comment: It looks to me like the target site doesn't support CORs so the OP will have to use JSONP to make a cross origin request.